# Good book on integral equation?

Tags: reference-request

I'm looking for a good reference on integral equations (i.e., an equation in which an unknown function appears under an integral sign such as the Fredholm equation). I would like something accessible but covers approaches to showing existence. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to tell exactly what you mean by "integral equations". Is it equations involving integers in number theory? Or the integrals we see in calculus? Or something else?

Comment: Search for "Smithies Integral equations" on Google books.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may think of this classic by [Grippenberg, Londen, Staffans](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521372895).

It is quite complete and also accessible compared to other books, but not an easy reading.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a well written book and easy to read by A. Jerri ["Introduction to Integral Equations with Applications"](http://www.amazon.ca/Introduction-Integral-Equations-Applications-Jerri/dp/0471317349/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1362148654&sr=1-1-fkmr0).

Answer (score 1):

Stephen M.Zemyan, *The Classical Theory of Integral Equations, A Concise Treatment*, Birkhauser
Recently, I'm reading this book. I think it is the best one for beginner.

Answer (score 1):

*Handbook of Integral Equations: Polyanin, Andrei D. Manzhirov*  is avaliable on the P2P servers or it can be found easily

it dealsh with integral equations how to solve it with examples and similar

Answer (score 1):

I am reading Linear Integral Equations by William Vernon Lovitt and finding it quite easy to understand. If you are a beginner, you should definitely try that.