# What are the good books for learning Integral equations

Tags: reference-request

I mainly study statistics. But I am interested in learning Integral equations. So what are the good books for learning Integral equations. I have no expertise in this topic. Any good lecture notes will also be helpful for me. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is an example of an integral equation that you are interested in?

Comment: @mixedmath : I mainly want to learn this topics: Linear integral equation of the first and second kind of Fredholm and Volterra type, Solutions with separable kernels. Characteristic numbers and eigenfunctions, resolvent kernel.

Comment: Probably the Handbook of Integral Equations.

Comment: Also look at Akheizer's posthumous notes. They are very good.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Good book on integral equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114995/good-book-on-integral-equation)